# Injection of GlimpseSecurityPolicy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, glimpse, ninject.web.mvc

I would like to implement my own `IRuntimePolicy`. I am following the given example, but I need to access our database or the best would be to have our UserSession object injected.

When is the security object created on runtime? Is this possible? I have not found any examples.

We use Ninject 3.2.3 I believe (or the latest available for MVC 5).

I imagine something like

```
public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy : IRuntimePolicy
    {
        private readonly IAclManager aclManager;
        private readonly IUserSession userSession;

        public GlimpseSecurityPolicy(IUserSession userSession, IAclManager aclManager)
        {
            this.userSession = userSession;
            this.aclManager = aclManager;
        }

        public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn
        {
            // check policy when request ends and when executing a resource (like glimpse.axd)
            get { return RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource; }
        }

        public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
        {
            if (!this.aclManager.IsUserAllowed(UserAction.AccessGlimpse, this.userSession.GetUser()))
            {
                return RuntimePolicy.Off;
            }

            return RuntimePolicy.On;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this a while back and go nowhere, I ended up using a service locator pattern to get round it. `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IThing>()`. You will also need a dependancyresolver bound in startup or global.asax. This is not great, i would love to see an alternative

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I have ended up with the same construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, we came up with only one option: to use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IThing>()`.

The code result is then straightforward and ugly:

```
public class GlimpseSecurityPolicy : IRuntimePolicy
    {
        public RuntimeEvent ExecuteOn => RuntimeEvent.EndRequest | RuntimeEvent.ExecuteResource;

        public RuntimePolicy Execute(IRuntimePolicyContext policyContext)
        {
            var aclManager = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAclManager>();
            var userSession = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserSession>();

            if (!aclManager.IsUserAllowed(UserAction.AccessGlimpse, userSession.GetUser()))
            {
                return RuntimePolicy.Off;
            }

            return RuntimePolicy.On;
        }
    }
```